# Deserializing Json to list of objects in C# with Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

So I am struggeling to parse the following JSON string. Even after researching many questions here on StackOverflow.

Json

```
[
  {
    "text": {
      "0": "Element 1"
    },
    "cascade": [],
    "val": "1"
  },
  {
    "text": {
      "0": "Element 2"
    },
    "cascade": [],
    "val": "2"
  },
  {
    "text": {
      "0": "Element 3"
    },
    "cascade": [],
    "val": "3"
  },
  {
    "text": {
      "0": "Unknown"
    },
    "cascade": [],
    "val": "0"
  }
]
```

The class I created for this looks like this:

Options.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace App.Models
{
  public class Options
  {
    public ICollection<IDictionary<string, string>> text { get; set; }
    public List<string> cascade { get; set; }
    public string val { get; set; }
  }
}
```

For running the deserialization I've written the following line:

```
List<Options> optionList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Options>>(inputString);
```

I'm getting the following exceptions when I try to run the code:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Timeout exceeded getting exception details

Comment: Try `public Dictionary<string, string> text { get; set; }`

Comment: if you paste your JSON into http://json2csharp.com/ it will suggest a data structure for you. It may not be the only way to do it, but it will suggest something which is likely to work. N.B. `List<string>` in your code seems inappropriate for "cascade", since it's an array in the JSON.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You problem is reading the "text" object.
From you sample, it contains key/value pairs of string type both.
There is no reason to use `ICollection` there, but only `Dictionary<string, string>`

```
public class Options
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> text { get; set; }
    public List<string> cascade { get; set; }
    public string val { get; set; }
}
```

**Update:**
Since your sample JSON does not include data about the `cascade` member (only an empty array), it might be safe declaring it as a list of objects `List<object>`.

Comment: `List<string> cascade` seems inadvisble, since it's just an empty array in the JSON - we don't know what it could contain. `List<object>` might be safer